# Ngrok giving authentication failed: Your account is not permitted to use the agent ingress "connect.ngrok-agent.com"

Tags: ngrok, tunnel

I have been using ngrok for quite a long time. But today when I try to run ngrok using command ngrok http 3000, The following error pops up. Any idea what's happening?

> NAME:   http - start an HTTP tunnel
>
> USAGE:   ngrok http [address:port | port] [flags]
>
> DESCRIPTION:    Starts a tunnel listening for HTTP/HTTPS traffic with
> a specific hostname.   The HTTP Host header on incoming public
> requests is inspected to   determine which tunnel it matches.
>
> HTTPS endpoints terminate TLS traffic at the ngrok server using the
> appropriate certificates. The decrypted, HTTP traffic is then
> forwarded   through the secure tunnel and then to your local server.
> If you don't want   your TLS traffic to terminate at the ngrok server,
> use a TLS or TCP tunnel.
>
> TERMS OF SERVICE: https://ngrok.com/tos
>
> EXAMPLES:    ngrok http 8080                             # forward
> ngrok subdomain to port 80   ngrok http example.com:9000
>
> ## forward traffic to example.com:9000   ngrok http --domain=bar.ngrok.dev 80        # request subdomain name: 'bar.ngrok.dev'   ngrok http --domain=example.com 1234
>
> request tunnel 'example.com' (DNS CNAME)   ngrok http
> --basic-auth='falken:joshua' 80  # enforce basic auth on tunnel endpoint   ngrok http --host-header=example.com 80     # rewrite the
> Host header to 'example.com'   ngrok http file:///var/log
>
> ## serve local files in /var/log   ngrok http https://localhost:8443           # forward to a local https server
>
> OPTIONS:
> --authtoken string                 ngrok.com authtoken identifying a user
> --basic-auth strings               enforce basic auth on tunnel endpoint, 'user:password'
> --cidr-allow strings               reject connections that do not match the given CIDRs
> --cidr-deny strings                reject connections that match the given CIDRs
> --circuit-breaker float            reject requests when 5XX responses exceed this ratio
> --compression                      gzip compress http responses from your web service
> --config strings                   path to config files; they are merged if multiple
> --domain string                    host tunnel on a custom subdomain or hostname (requires DNS CNAME)   -h, --help
> help for http
> --host-header string               set Host header; if 'rewrite' use local address hostname
> --inspect                          enable/disable http introspection (default true) (default )
> --log string                       path to log file, 'stdout', 'stderr' or 'false' (default "false")
> --log-format string                log record format: 'term', 'logfmt', 'json' (default "term")
> --log-level string                 logging level: 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'crit' (default "info")
> --mutual-tls-cas string            path to TLS certificate authority to verify client certs in mutual tls
> --oauth string                     enforce authentication oauth provider on tunnel endpoint, e.g. 'google'
> --oauth-allow-domain strings       allow only oauth users with these email domains
> --oauth-allow-email strings        allow only oauth users with these emails
> --oauth-client-id string           oauth app client id, optional
> --oauth-client-secret string       oauth app client secret, optional
> --oauth-scope strings              request these oauth scopes when users authenticate
> --oidc string                      oidc issuer url, e.g. https://accounts.google.com
> --oidc-client-id string            oidc app client id
> --oidc-client-secret string        oidc app client secret
> --oidc-scope strings               request these oidc scopes when users authenticate
> --proxy-proto string               version of proxy proto to use with this tunnel, empty if not using
> --region string                    ngrok server region [us, eu, au, ap, sa, jp, in] (default "us")
> --request-header-add strings       header key:value to add to request
> --request-header-remove strings    header field to remove from request if present
> --response-header-add strings      header key:value to add to response
> --response-header-remove strings   header field to remove from response if present
> --scheme strings                   which schemes to listen on (default [https])
> --verify-webhook string            validate webhooks are signed by this provider, e.g. 'slack'
> --verify-webhook-secret string     secret used by provider to sign webhooks, if any
> --websocket-tcp-converter          convert ingress websocket connections to TCP upstream
>
> ERROR:  authentication failed: Your account is not permitted to use
> the agent ingress "connect.ngrok-agent.com". ERROR:   ERROR:
> ERR_NGROK_122 ERROR:
>
> Trying ngrok http 3000. Ngrok website says its ERR_NGROK_122:
>
> https://ngrok.com/docs/errors/err_ngrok_122/

Comment: Same here. I started facing this problem just a few minutes ago.

Comment: Looks like its a major network problem from Ngrok. I just got this error now. ERR_NGROK_122: Your account is not permitted to use the agent ingress "connect.ngrok-agent.com".

Comment: Looks like their network was down. But it is working again now

Comment: Yes, tried on my local machine. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like ngrok's network was down. It's working fine now